# $K_{2^p+1}$ is not a union of $p$ bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry

What I want to show is that among $2^p+1$ points in the plane there are three that determine an angle of size at least $\pi(1-1/p)$.

I was told I have to start with showing for $n=2^p$ that the graph $K_{n+1}$ is not the union of $p$ bipartite graphs but $K_n$ is.

I have no idea how to prove this. My first ideas were induction or proof by contradition but neither was helpful. It could also have something to do with the fact that every bipartite grpah is 2-colourable.

Comment: To show that $K_{2^p}$ *is* the union of $p$ bipartite graphs, here's a hint: Label the vertices $v_0$ through $v_{2^p-1}$ using the base-2 representations of the integers 0 to ${2^p-1}$. Does this suggest a way to choose $p$ bipartitions of the vertices?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the 2-base representation? I think this suggests a way to choose p bipartitions s.t every two vertices which have a different colour are put into one partition, I continue doing so 2^p-times

Comment: Base-2 representation is using the two digits 0 and 1, instead of the usual 10 digits 0, 1, 2, ..., 9. So, for example the base-2 representation of the number 25 is 11001, for $1\times16+1\times8+0\times4+0\times2+1\times1$. By the way, for my suggestion, pad with zeroes to use $p$ digits for each integer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am sorry I do not see how it helps me to find a way to choose $p$ bipartitions of he vertices.

Comment: Ulrich, try this: Let the $i$-th bipartition of $\{v_0,\dots,v_{2^p-1}\}$ be $(V_i,W_i)$, where $V_i$ is the set of vertices $v_j$ where the integer $j$ has the digit 1 as its $i$-th bit (from the right) in the binary representation of $j$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

*Proposition*. The graph $K_{2^p+1}$ is not a union of $p$ bipartite graphs.

*Proof*. Assume the converse: there exists a family $\{\Gamma_i:i\in [p]=\{1,\dots,p\}\}$ of bipartite subgraphs of a graph $\Gamma=K_{2^p+1}$ such that $\Gamma$ is the union of the family $\{\Gamma_i\}$. Let $(V_i ,W_i)$ be the bipartition of vertices of the graph $\Gamma_i$.  Let $\Delta_i$ be a full bipartite graph with the bipartition $V_i\cup (V\setminus V_i)$ of the vertices, where $V$ is the set of all of vertices of the graph $\Gamma$. Then $\Gamma_i$ is a subgraph of  $\Delta_i$ and $\Delta_i$ is a subgraph of $\Gamma$. Then  $\Gamma$ is the union of the family $\{\Delta_i\}$. Now define a map $f:V\to\{0,1\}^p$ as follows. Let $v$ be a vertex of the graph $\Gamma$. For each index $i$ put $f_i(v)=0$ if $v\in V_i$ and $f_i(v)=1$, otherwise. Put $f=\prod_{i\in [p]} f$, that is $f(v)=(f_1(v),\dots, f_p(v)).$  Since $|V|=2^p+1>2^p=|\{0,1\}^p |$, there exist different vertices $v_1,v_2\in V$  such that $f(v_1)=f(v_2)$. But then the edge between $v_1$ and $v_2$ does not belong to each of the graphs $\Delta_i$, a contradiction.